# Problem installing xgboost! Have tried below two methods but still doesn't recognise the module in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, xgboost, anaconda3

Have tried installing xgboost using 'pip install xgboost' while it installed but when I launch jupyter notebook, it said module not found.

And when I tried installing using conda, it showed below error. How do I change user rights to write to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3?

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Answer (score 1):

Start your command prompt with run as administrator